# Can normal users be granted permission to run signed installers (MSI)?

Tags: permissions, windows-installer

I'm working on deploying a .NET desktop application via ClickOnce and need the users to be able to run the prerequisite installers. Normal users generally do not have permission to run installers, but is it possible for those users to be granted permission to run installers signed by a company-issued certificate?

Answer (score 2):

You can control this by group policies, but it depends on the version of the OS.  Windows 7 has a nice feature called [Applocker](http://4sysops.com/archives/review-windows-7-applocker-part-1-overview/) that allows you to create *Windows Installer Rules* & say things like allow this installer to run from this publisher.
There are some [group policies in XP](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc739980%28WS.10%29.aspx) for allowing regular users to get elevated install privileges, but I think that’s only for things deployed via windows installer (i.e. MSI's).

Depending on what your trying to achieve, it may be easier to [assign/publish the application](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc783635%28WS.10%29.aspx) completely via group policy.